# message from trigger is not displayed

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have created trigger for checking value length. I want display my own message than length is more than specified. Trigger was created without error. But If I try create record with value more than specified I get only system error. How make so I see also my message? Thanks

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_region_name_length
ON Region
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT inserted.RegionName FROM inserted
WHERE LEN(inserted.RegionName)>10
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('RegionName value is longer than specified', 10, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN;
END;
END    
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic data integrity checks are performed well *before* a trigger fires, and if they fail, the trigger is never invoked at all.

As such, if you're trying to replace or augment an existing warning (i.e. if the column's length is defined as `(10)`), you're on a hiding to nothing trying to set a new error message from a trigger.

E.g.:

```
create table T (Val1 char(1) not null)
go
create trigger T_T on T instead of insert
as
    insert into T (Val1)
    select SUBSTRING(Val1,1,1) from inserted
go
insert into T (Val1) values ('ab')
```

Produces:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>
> String or binary data would be truncated.
> The statement has been terminated.

Even though, *had* the trigger been allowed to fire, it would have performed a successful insert.

Comment: so, as I understand there is no posiibility to replace system message (which arise than data integrity check fails) or add to this message my?

Comment: @genky - No, there's no way to replace the message, or add an extra one, from the SQL Server side.

Comment: but would my message visible on UI part of application, which use appropriate database?

Comment: @genky - If you're wanting to display helpful (to the user) messages, then the UI is going to be the place to generate them - either pre-validate (by reading the appropriate metadata from the server) before attempting, or react to the errors that SQL Server generates. Unfortunately, the errors that SQL Server generates don't assist you much with identifying *where* there's a mismatch between your submitted data and the basic integrity checks.